# Is there any way to get Microk8s snap working in Raspberry Pi Ubuntu Core 20

Tags: raspberrypi, ubuntu-core, microk8s

I have Raspberry Pi 4 with 4GB menory and 64GB memory card. I followed [this tutorial](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/getting-started-with-microk8s-on-ubuntu-core#1-introduction) to install microk8s. In ubuntu core install part the tutorial says: "we recommend you select the latest version of Ubuntu Core 32-bit armhf". I did that and when I try to install microk8s I get:

`myname@ubuntu:~$ snap install microk8s --channel=latest/edge/strict                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        error: snap "microk8s" is not available on edge/strict for this architecture (armhf) but exists on                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  other architectures (amd64, arm64, ppc64el, s390x).`

I then installed the 64-bit ubuntu core 20 instead. I can install and start microk8s but when I try to follow the tutorial and give  `sudo microk8s status --wait-ready`, it never returns (never means more than 30 mins).

So it seems that the microk8s is not really working on core at all. I did not try other channels on microk8s since the edge was recommended in tutorial and also in one of the ask ubuntu questions. I wasted a day already on tutorials that do not work.

Answer (score 0):

Googling that error message leads me to https://github.com/ubuntu/microk8s/issues/228, which clearly states that 32-bit (armhf) if not supported, and no binaries are built for it.

Since the Pi4 is a 64-bit machine (Pi2 and Pi3 are indeed 32-bit-only), try following the tutorials again, but select the arm64 build instead of the armhf build of Ubuntu Core.

You can also leave feedback on the tutorials; there's a link on each tutorial page. The authors welcome constructive, specific suggestions for improving and clarifying. Constructive improvement from users is how Ubuntu gets better. For example, you might suggest that the how-to-install-Ubuntu-Core tutorial is misleading for microk8s users, since it recommends armhf. Or the microk8s tutorial needs to specify arm64.

Comment: I wrote "I then installed the 64-bit ubuntu core 20 instead" so I did select arm64 option. As I described It did not work either. I would like to know is there any way to get microk8s working in Ubuntu core on raspberry Pi?

Comment: I also left a suggestion for tutorial about armhf.